# Autocomplete taxonomy with depth field

Tags: 8, entities, taxonomy-terms

I am looking to achieve the next functionality:

I have a content type about fruits, I've added an autocomplete taxonomy field to the content type with the possibility to register new taxonomy.

I would like to achieve some taxonomy depth.

I am using the [autocomplete deluxe module](https://www.drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe)

For example, I input in the field *apple*, *fresh*, and *green*.

[image: screenshot]

When I go to the *fruits* taxonomy vocabulary, I would like to have the taxonomy depth like this.

[image: screenshot]

Instead, I get the following.

[image: screenshot]

Is there a way to achieve this with taxonomy autocomplete field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest implementing hook_entity_presave() getting values from taxonomy term reference field. If always the pre-term will be the parent of the current term then loop through the results of the term ids:

[image]

```
 if ($entity->getEntityTypeId() == 'node') {
    if ($entity->bundle() == 'Machine_Name_content_type') {
    // Get the values from taxonomy term:
    $terms = $entity->get('field_tags')->getValue();
    if (!empty($terms)) {
        foreach($terms as $key => $value) {
            // Exclude the first term because this will be the parent.
            if ($key != '0') {
                // Get the parent of the element.
                $parent = $terms[$key -1];
                // Load the current term.
                $term_loaded= \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::load($value['target_id']);
                // Set the parent: the term before.
                $term_loaded->parent = ['target_id' => $parent['target_id']];
                $term_loaded->save();
            }
        }

     }
  }
}
```

Hope to help you!